# Why Flash Player versions showing different on Microsoft Edge anf Firefox

Tags: firefox, microsoft-edge, flash

Before installing Flash player I uninstalled older version. Uninstallation was incomplete without deleting the ActiveX  files from the sys32 macromed/flash and sys64 macromed/flash folder.

I also removed FlashPlayerApp, FlashplayerCPLAPp and FlashplayerInstaller  from sys64 folder.

Next I installed latest version of Flash player 26.0.0.126 that support firefox.

Flash Player  working fine on firefox. 
Microsoft Edge does not play flash now. I restored all the deleted ActiveX files.
The version that is showing on edge is the old version 25.0.0.121.

Since the ActiveX file does not come with Flash player installation.

I would like to know the procedure to update flash player ActiveX files on Microsoft Edge

Comment: (1) Since this is not a **programming** issue, better to ask at [**SuperUser.com**](https://superuser.com/) since that site deals with general software usage issues (you can use same account there, click "Join this community")

Comment: (2) _"...the procedure to update flash player ActiveX files on Microsoft Edge"_ What version of Windows you using? All I know is that Flash is already built-in inside Edge browser and will auto-update the plugin. **ActiveX** is a Microsoft technology to load plugin, Firefox uses alternative NPAPI method to load plugin (Chrome uses Google's own PPAPI). Sometimes ActiveX, PPAPI and NPAPI can be at different version numbers (same software, just different numbering systems)

Comment: Does the FlashUtil_AcitveX.exe and FlashUtil_ActiveX.dll inside the macromed/flash folder get updated with Flash Installation. I don't see these files when installed flash player.  Windows 10 is the OS